# storm nimbus not starting: Getting below error

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-storm

```
$ storm nimbus
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/chefsolo/apache-storm-0.9.1-incubating/bin/storm", line 455, in <m                                            odule>

  main()

  File "/home/chefsolo/apache-storm-0.9.1-incubating/bin/storm", line 452, in ma                                            in

  (COMMANDS.get(COMMAND, unknown_command))(*ARGS)

  File "/home/chefsolo/apache-storm-0.9.1-incubating/bin/storm", line 268, in ni                                            mbus

  jvmopts = parse_args(confvalue("nimbus.childopts", cppaths)) + [

  File "/home/chefsolo/apache-storm-0.9.1-incubating/bin/storm", line 81, in con                                            fvalue

  p = sub.Popen(command, stdout=sub.PIPE)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: how do you slove the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly Storm cannot find JAVAHOME in your computer. Here is how to fix it.

1. Open storm_env.ini file in storm conf folder.
2. Find line that configures alternate JAVAHOME
   if you are accessing for the first time it'll look like this
   #The java implementation to use. If JAVA_HOME is not found we expect java to be in path
   #JAVA_HOME:home
3. Update it with your JAVAHOME

   ex (this how it looks in my file.):

   #The java implementation to use. If JAVA_HOME is not found we expect java to be in path

   JAVA_HOME:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
4. Save changes and close the editor.
5. Open new terminal and try again

Answer (score 0):

Which python version you are using? It is probably not able to locate the `usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py` file which comes with `python 2.7` and you are currently running with `python 2.6`